# Issue while consuming axis2 webservice behind proxy

Tags: java, web-services, proxy

My server is in a network where all the internet request are to go through proxy. I have configured proxy for my jvm with -Dhttp.proxy.. system properties. When the webservice (which is on internet) is accessed, I get following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:221)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:452)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:330)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.execute(OutInAxisOperation.java:294)
```

What could be the solution for the same?

Comment: It says `Connection refused` meaning its finding the host be the port is not correct. Can you make sure that the port is correct ?

Comment: are you working with any IDE?

Comment: @Santosh: That is not the reason, the host and port are correct and I have reconfirmed it.

Comment: @Prabha: This is error from the deployed application in a server.

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: @DiogoMoreira: Jboss 7.0 AS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the proxy properties in code with:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port);

// Maybe these are required now
AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port);
```

Just make sure these properties are set *before* any axis call is made. This may seem obvious but you might face problems when you set the properties on a 'retry' kind of call *afterwards*.

Comment: I can not change the code as i already mentioned. Is there any way through configuration?

Comment: You can give this a shot setting the properties in your code right before you call the library which executes the Axis call as these settings are set globally for the VM.

Setting `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` may also be helpful.

Comment: As already written, I can not change code. That is the restriction I have in this case. And i already tried useSystemProxies=true but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe the proxy requires authentication, or you have some SOCKS proxy in there. Maybe play with [these options][http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies] or even better ask the network proxy team why your connection get's refused.


Worst case you need to contact the vendor to upgrade the software to handle proxies properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell axis to use a proxy? I think axis doesn't know yet. Just setting the global jvm properties will not tell axis to use this proxy.

Comment: And how do i do that?, I can not change the code as i already mentioned. Is there any way through configuration?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try checking the connection to the proxy is good with some other tool?
Check for Host/Post/User/Password etc.,

Otherwise, try changing the network connection of the host to use proxy and try hitting.

(I know, I'm just trying to debug the issue here) ;-)

Comment: There is no problem with the proxy server, any code with normal HTTPURLConnection works fine.